# How to prove this mathematical result about the Green's displacement tensor?

Tags: scattering, tensor-calculus, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

In [this](http://scitation.aip.org/content/asa/journal/jasa/59/6/10.1121/1.381022)  paper on integral equations for the scattering of elastic waves, the authors use the following result in their derivation:

$$\mathbf{T}:\nabla \mathbf{G}-\nabla \mathbf{u}:\mathbf{\Sigma}=0$$

where $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},\omega)$ and $\mathbf{T}=\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x},\omega)$ are the displacement vector and the stress tensor, respectively, in an isotropic elastic solid, and $\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega)$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}=\mathbf{\Sigma}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega)$ are the second rank Green's displacement tensor and the third rank Green's stress tensor, respectively. I need help in proving the above result.

---

### Background

The displacement vector and the stress tensor in an isotropic elastic solid with Lam$\acute{e}$ constants $\lambda$ and $\mu$ satisfy the following relationship

$$\mathbf{T} = \lambda(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}) \mathbf{I} + \mu (\nabla \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{u} \nabla )$$

where $\mathbf{I}$ is the unit dyadic. In the indicial notation, the above equation reads

$$T_{ij} = \lambda\ \partial_ku_k\ \delta_{ij} + \mu(\partial_i u_j + \partial_j u_i)$$

The displacement vector $\mathbf{u}$ satisfies the following wave equation inside the solid

$$ [(\lambda+\mu)\nabla\nabla\cdot+\mu\nabla^2]\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},\omega)+\rho\omega^2\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},\omega) = -\rho \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\omega) $$

where $x$ is the position vector, $\rho$ is the mass density of the solid and $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\omega)$ is the vector of body forces. The displacement field inside the solid for a point source at $\mathbf{x'}$ is defined as the Green's displacement tensor and it satisfies the following equation

$$ [(\lambda+\mu)\nabla\nabla\cdot+\mu\nabla^2]\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega)+\rho\omega^2\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega) = - \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'})\mathbf{I}$$

The Green's displacement tensor shown above is a second rank tensor. The corresponding stress field will be a third rank tensor and is related to the Green's displacement tensor as follows

$$\mathbf{\Sigma}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega) = \lambda \mathbf{I} \nabla\cdot\mathbf{G} + \mu (\nabla \mathbf{G} + \mathbf{G} \nabla )$$

or in the indicial notation

$$\Sigma_{ijk} = \lambda\ \delta_{ij}\partial_lG_{lk}\  + \mu(\partial_i G_{jk} + \partial_k G_{ij})$$

A closed form expression for the Green's displacement tensor can be obtained in terms of the Green's functions of two different scalar Helmholtz equations, one corresponding to the longitudinal (compressional) waves and the other to the shear waves.

$$G_{mn}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega) 
= \frac{1}{4\pi\rho\omega^2} \left[ \left( \delta_{mn}\ k_s^2 + \partial_m\partial_n \right)g_s(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega) - \partial_m\partial_n g_c(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega) \right]$$

where $g_c(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega)=\exp(ik_c|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|)/|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|$ and  $g_s(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x'},\omega)=\exp(ik_s|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|)/|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|$, with $k_s^2 = \rho \omega^2 / \mu$ and $k_c^2=\rho\omega^2/(\lambda+\mu)$.

---

### My attempt

The concerned result can be written in the indicial notation as follows:

$$\left[\mathbf{T}:\nabla \mathbf{G}-\nabla \mathbf{u}:\mathbf{\Sigma}\right]_l = T_{jk}(\partial_jG_{kl})-(\partial_j u_k)\Sigma_{jkl}$$

Then by writing the components of the stress tensors $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ in terms of the components of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{G}$, respectively, we obtain

\begin{align}
\left[\mathbf{T}:\nabla \mathbf{G}-\nabla \mathbf{u}:\mathbf{\Sigma}\right]_l =& \left[ \lambda\ \partial_i u_i\ \delta_{jk} + \mu(\partial_j u_k + \partial_k u_j) \right](\partial_j G_{kl}) \\
&+ (\partial_j u_k) \left[ \lambda\ \delta_{jk}\partial_iG_{il}
 + \mu(\partial_j G_{kl} + \partial_l G_{jk}) \right] \\
= & \lambda(\partial_i u_i) \partial_j G_{jl} + \mu (\partial_j u_k) \partial_j G_{kl} + \mu (\partial_k u_j) \partial_j G_{kl} \\
& - \lambda (\partial_j u_j) \partial_i G_{il} - \mu (\partial_j u_k) \partial_j G_{kl} - \mu (\partial_j u_k) \partial_l G_{jk}
\end{align}

The first and the second terms cancel with the fourth and the fifth terms, respectively, leaving

\begin{align} 
\left[\mathbf{T}:\nabla \mathbf{G}-\nabla \mathbf{u}:\mathbf{\Sigma}\right]_l =& \mu (\partial_k u_j) \partial_j G_{kl} - \mu (\partial_j u_k) \partial_l G_{jk} \\
=& \mu (\partial_k u_j) \left[ \partial_j G_{kl} - \partial_l G_{kj} \right]
\end{align}

Now by substituting the closed form expression of the Green's displacement tensor shown above, the terms involving the double partial derivatives (in the Green's displacement tensor) cancel each other leaving the following equation

\begin{align} 
\left[\mathbf{T}:\nabla \mathbf{G}-\nabla \mathbf{u}:\mathbf{\Sigma}\right]_l =& \mu (\partial_k u_j) \left[  \delta_{kl} \partial_j g -  \delta_{kj} \partial_l g \right]
\end{align}

where $g=g_s(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x},\omega)$ is the scalar Green's function for the shear waves. How to proceed from here?

Comment: I see that you have a third order stress tensor. Is this some kind of generalized notion of stress? If you think of stresses (Cauchy, Piola-Kirchhoff etc) as maps relating normals and tractions, they are always of second order.

Comment: @user_of_math  The displacement corresponding to a point source oriented in a particular direction (say x direction) is a vector. When point sources in all three directions (x, y and z) are considered, the solution can be written in a compact form as a tensor of order 2. This is the fundamental solution for the displacement, denoted by $\mathbf{G}$ in my question. Similarly, the corresponding traction can be written as a second order tensor.

Comment: The stress tensor $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is third order because it is derived from $\mathbf{G}$ by the application of the Hooke's law. This is the fundamental solution for the stress and it relates the normals to the fundamental solution for traction, which is a second order tensor.

Comment: @user_of_math Thanks for your interest in this question. It turns out that the expression for $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{ijk}$ in my question is wrong. I have made a mistake while going from the coordinate-free notation to the indicial notation for $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. The correct expression for $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{ijk}$ is $$\Sigma_{ijk} = \lambda\ \delta_{ij}\partial_lG_{lk}\  + \mu(\partial_i G_{jk} + \partial_j G_{ik})$$ The difference is in the last term. The result I was looking for follows after this correction.